# Help with radical equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Please, help me to solve this equation. No advanced math should be needed.

$$
3x^2 - 4x + \sqrt{3x^2 - 4x - 6} = 18
$$

I'm clueless. It should be simple.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Certainly the square root sign is a nuisance. Can you try to get rid of it?

Comment: To simplify, let $z=3x^2-4x-6$. Then your equation is $z+\sqrt z=12$.

Comment: Denote by $y=\sqrt{3x^2-x-6}$

Comment: @DavidMitra Wow, that's super smart! I would've never thought of that! I'll try it!

Comment: @BeetleTheNeato Several answers provided below are smarter :)

Comment: I tried lots of things... I noticed that $3x^2 - 4x$ is repeated, so I tried to substitute it for a simpler variable. But it doesn't simplify anything, the numbers become unworkable without a calculator.

I tried isolating the root and then squaring both sides, but then I'm left with a 4th degree polynomial expression...

Anyway, I'll try what David suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : set $u:= \sqrt{3 x^2-4x-6}$ then your equation becomes $u^2+6+u=18$ or $$u^2+u-12=0$$

Answer (score 3):

No advanced math is needed.

- Denote $u = \sqrt{3 x^2 - 4x -6}$.
- Write the original equation in terms of $u$. You should get a quadratic equation.
- Solve it.
- For each root $u_\ast$ found, solve $3 x^2 - 4x -6 = u_\ast^2$.
- Verify your solutions against the original equation and weed out [extraneous solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions).

Answer (score 1):

Put $u = 3x^2 - 4x$.  Then the equation becomes
$$ u + \sqrt{u - 6} = 18.$$
Once you solve for $u$ in the auxillary equation, you are left with a quadratic.

Comment: Two comments appeared whilst I was writing this.  These methods will also work; we are all playing variations on a theme.